# Hi, please am trying to put seconds before the link is redirected

Tags: timeout

Here is the code I have done, all I need now is the timer code so it can wait before the redirect

```
<script>
  window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/home.html";
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the code I have done, all I need now is the timer code so it can wait before the redirect
Hi, please am trying to put seconds before the link is redirected, I know how to do this in jquery, but not in javascript so please help me with it here's the code  
want it to wait at least 20 seconds before the redirect

    <script>
      window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/home.html";
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/home.html";
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: WOW Bro thanks it works, thanks so much, also I want it to wait at least 10 seconds after the Dom/website have fully loaded, thanks in advance

Comment: @kevinigwilo, sure :) check out the excellent beginner tutorial at w3schools on js https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp